# Consumer Count / pending Message Count from Queue + ActiveMQ + Java

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-data-mongodb

I have to develop the Utility in Java which will use the ActiveMQ API to get the properties of Queue/Topic to get the No of Consumers / No of Pending Messages and also is there any way I can delete any Message thru Code from Queue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use the [Statistics Plugin](http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html) to get the consumer count, pending counts etc.

About deleting/removing any particular message from queue, I would recommend not to do that in a separate program but just let your message consumers handle such messages. That would be more maintainable approach I think.

Answer (score 0):

All the below details are with respect to Queue API of ActiveMQ, you can find similar things for topic as well

- No of Pending messages can be found by using `getMessages().size()`
- No of consumers can be found by `getConSumers().size()`
- yes , we can delete messages onto queue from Java code, but we need
  `MessageReference` or the `messageId` or a suitable `message Selector` for this to happen, you can have a look at official
  documentation of `removeMessage(...)` and
  `removeMatchingMessages(...)` [here](http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/region/Queue.html)

hope this helps!

Good luck!